# Enable virtualization with gigabyte ud3 990fx

Tags: virtual-machine, hardware, cpu

I'm trying to get the virtualization running : 
I have the following settings:

1. Mainboard: gigabyte ud3 990fx
2. CPU: fx-9590
3. Kernel: 3.11.0-12-generic
4. Linux Mint 17
5. In the bios both svm as well as IOMMU are enabled

Though these settings, I have no virtualization enabled

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -E "svm|vmx"
```

is empty

and kvm-ok command yields:
"Your CPU does not support KVM extensions"

I checked the cpu specs, its a quite new cpu and it DOES support virtualization.
Any idea what have I missed?

Comment: Most probably, it has got to do something with the BIOS setttings. Do you have the `Virtualization` option enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: as said in 5. yes the svm is enabled in the bios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep is incorrect use

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -iE "svm|vmx"
```

if return something is ok.
If didn't return nothing,try another kernel maybe more recent.

Comment: I have updated the question with the kernel version. It is a recent one

Comment: Try more recent,for example 4.0.4

Comment: THAT WAS IT!!!!. Thanks to your advice I have not svm enabled. I never imagined that kernel 3.11 is old enough not to have svm support. Again thanks!!

Comment: 3.11 has svm support,but of course not for most recent cpu